# Add -shell-escape option to the LaTeX invocation of preview-latex in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex, preview, shell-escape

I need `preview-latex` to use the `-shell-escape` option when it invokes PDFLaTeX, which is required by the [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) package for syntax highlighting, as it invokes python. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [preview-latex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/preview-latex.html#Top) documentation :

> preview-LaTeX-command
>
> When you generate previews on a buffer or a region, the command in preview-LaTeX-command gets run (that variable should only be changed with Customize since its structure is somewhat peculiar, though expressive). As usual with AUCTeX, you can continue working while this is going on. It is not a good idea to change the file until after preview-latex has established where to place the previews which it can only do after the LaTeX run completes. This run produces a host of pseudo-error messages that get parsed by preview-latex at the end of the LaTeX run and give it the necessary information about where in the source file the LaTeX code for the various previews is located exactly. The parsing takes a moment and will render Emacs busy.

Browse the `AUCTeX` customize-group to `>Preview > Preview Latex` and find the option `Preview latex command`.
Unfolded, it looks this way :

[image]

Replacing the line

```
%`%l "\nonstopmode\nofiles\PassOptionsToPackage{
```

with

```
%`%l -shell-escape "\nonstopmode\nofiles\PassOptionsToPackage{
```

should do the trick. Don't forget to click "Set for current session", and "Save for future sessions" if it works!

Comment: awesome, that works. Actually, I was already looking at customizing this variable `preview-LaTeX-command`, but wasn't sure where in all these strings to add the option, so I figured it would be nice to ask, so someone else with the same problem could find a solution quicker than me :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, I changed the settings through the UI, and looked at what was being written out to .emacs - the parts that are pertinent for this question are

```
(custom-set-variables
 ....
 ....
 '(preview-LaTeX-command (quote ("%`%l -shell-escape \"\\nonstopmode\\nofiles\\PassOptionsToPackage{" ("," . preview-required-option-list) "}{preview}\\AtBeginDocument{\\ifx\\ifPreview\\undefined" preview-default-preamble "\\fi}\"%' %t")))
 ...
 ...
)
```